# Applications of polynomial systems of equations

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, systems-of-equations, applications

What are some applications of Polynomial Systems of Equations?

I am doing a project with Artificial Neural Networks where I use standard ANNs with a different backpropagation algorithm to find solutions of a SOPE.

Comment: For example, deciding whether a given graph is $2$-colorable can be reduced to deciding whether a system of linear and quadratic equations is feasible. You may want to take a look at [Expressing Combinatorial Optimization Problems by Systems of Polynomial Equations and the Nullstellensatz](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0578) (2007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing [tensor rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition) is currently a quite hot topic in the numerical linear algebra community and involve solving systems of polynomial equations. In short, the tensor rank decomposition can be seen as an SVD decomposition but for "matrices" with more than 2 indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also know there is some sort of application in neuro-physiology, I don't know exactly what it does though.

Comment: well computing tensor decompositions have **a lot** of applications for instance solving large scale PDEs, machine learning, signal processing, quantum physics, etc. Although already quite old for the field, this survey gives some interesting references: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/07070111X

Comment: By the way, do you have a paper/preprint about your work?

Comment: Is there a more straightforward real world application of this? Something the people outside the mathematical community would care about?